# Debugging websites on stock Android browser (not Chrome!)

Tags: android, html, css, remote-debugging, android-browser

The question is simple: how to debug a website on Android stock browser? I know about the [remote debugging feature](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), but it's only available through Chrome for Android (pretty useless for me - website is displayed improperly only on stock browser).

Answer (score 2):

> weinre is WEb INspector REmote. Pronounced like the word "winery". Or
>   maybe like the word "weiner". Who knows, really.
>
> weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web
>   Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work
>   remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile
>   device such as a phone.

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest

From source:

> Libraries not supported
>
> versions of Prototype.js before version 1.7 are not supported, as they
>   do not support the JSON.stringify() API correctly. You will get an
>   alert() in the web page you are debugging if you attempt to debug it
>   with weinre and you are using an unsupported version of Prototype.js.
>   Platforms supported - debug server
>
> Any platform that supports node.js.
>
> Platforms supported - debug client
>
> The browser where the debugger user interface runs.
>
> Google Chrome Apple Safari Other recent-ish WebKit-based browsers
>   Platforms supported - debug target
>
> The browser with the page you are debugging.
>
> Android Browser application iOS Mobile Safari application
>   PhoneGap/Cordova other Platforms not supported - debug target
>
> iOS 3.1.3 or earlier webOS 1.45 or earlier